# Report's text field's "stretch with over flow" option add empty row in PDF export

Tags: jasper-reports

I have set the "Stretch With Overflow" option True to some text fields , when the data over flow in the jasper viewer is working correctly, the text is on 2 rows but in PDF document the second row is empty: it just adds an empty row.

[image: PDF Document]

[image: Jasper Viewer]

Exemple xml code :

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
<reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="165" y="0" width="35" height="10" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="a5d7ff35-a2dc-480e-80a7-9246d8618b27"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left">
        <font fontName="Futura Std Light" size="7"/>
        <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{montant} == null && $F{numeroAppelant} != null ? $F{numeroAppele}.toString():
                        $F{duree} != null ? $F{duree}.toString() :
                        $F{volumeKo} != null ? null : $F{montant}.toString()]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: please post relevant XML code from your report... if possible, a testable one.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have testable XML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,
I just set the line spacing property to 1.5 !

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I change the font, it works wright. The problem that the same font on another report works fine with stretch with overflow option.